# One test case failed for the python solution. How to correct it.?

Tags: python

I was solving a problem in IndiaHacks in python but one of the test case failed. But when i solved using the same logic in C++ , all the test cases passed.

I figured out that's because of python not being able to get full string as input if the string length is long.

Here is the [problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/game-of-thornes-2/)

This is my solution in python

```
a=input()
s = set(a)

dic = {}

for v in s:
    dic[v] = a.count(v)

if((len(a))%2 == 0):
   ne = set(dic.values())
   if len(ne) == 1:
       print("YES")
   else:
       print("NO")
else:

    co = 0
    for ky in dic:
        if dic[ky]%2 != 0:
            co = co +1
    if co==1:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Here is the input test case which [failed](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/indiahacks-code-mania-7/problems/0457281c-a-input-0457222.txt?Signature=WuxZR1puZYWloDR99K%2F6dqxWfLs%3D&Expires=1506138743&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ)

PS: My algorithm is correct . Its just that variable a is not able to get the full string as input.How to get that ? Is there long string in python..?

Comment: The logic when `(len(a))%2 == 0` seems broken. You should check that each value is even.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this -

```
x = sys.stdin.read()
```

Please note that you have to import sys for using this.

Comment: I tried that too, not working. The string input in that test case is too long and the python is not able to take the whole string as input.

Here is the [link](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/indiahacks-code-mania-7/problems/0457281c-a-input-0457222.txt?Signature=bOSO4H5mSXaWxoiB0ELyWQAy79U%3D&Expires=1506489592&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ) to the input.